# Neural network classification always return same label one it has hidden layer , regardless input

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I used MatConvNet to test a feedforward net for three-classes classification problem.

My input data has 5 features and the net work topology as follows:

*hidden layer ：1 node with 5 weights & 1 bias
activation func : sigmoid

*output layer : 3 nodes each of them have 1 weights & 1 bias
activation func : sigmoid / softmax + loss

the problem is like this, no matter how i change the network's topology, as along as the network has hidden layers, it always return same label for any input. Moreover once i add hidden layers, the network always converge within 3 epoch.[here is how it converged with hidden layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x37Ok.png)

[image]

however the network could run "normally"(gives different label) if it doesn't have any hidden layer.

I have tried:

*normalized the input data

*subtract mean

*change to different activation func, sigmoid/softmax

but none of them works....

so anyone know what's wrong with this problem? 
thanks.

Comment: With 1 hidden node, it is almost impossible to distinguish 3 classes. I'd try with 3 nodes in the hidden layer. Further, if the image you show is the classification error, then it doesn't learn much: 0.38 = 38% correct is bad, as even random should get 33% correct.

Comment: actually i tried different nodes in hidden layer, also different number of hidden layer. but always return same result. exactly same classification error, and exactly same graphic as i showed before.

Comment: Then it is likely a bug in your code. Please edit your question to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)